# Update child when parents change: Process Builder

Tags: process-builder

I have this formula for updating a child's field value:

```
IF([Child__c].FirstParent__r.Field__c < 50, [Child__c].ChildsField__c,
    IF([Child__c].FirstParent__r.Field__c < 85, 60,
        IF([Child__c].FirstParent__r.Field__c > 85, 100, 0)
    )
)-IF([Child__c].SecondParent__r.Field__c , 10, 0)
```

As you can see, I'm using here a child's field and 2 fields of different parents. To check parents' changes I use this condition:

```
OR(ISCHANGED([Child__c].FirstParent__r.Field__c),
    ISCHANGED([Child__c].SecondParent__r.Field__c),
    ISCHANGED([Child__c].ChildsField__c)
)
```

But it works only when the `ChildsField__c` is changed. What should I fix here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have written the process builder on Child__c object. So Process Builder will only get fired when any of Child__c field is changed. This Process will not get fired if any of the FirstParent or Second Parent field is updated.
To accommodate this, you should add additional logic that takes care.

Comment: I think I can't do it with other processes because of different parents in the formula for the value. I can't see other parents in this child via one of the parents. It looks like I should use a code.